# How and where do I confirm TCP ports are open when performing mirroring? (Principal, Mirror & Witness)

Tags: sql-server, mirroring

I have a SQL 2017 Principal, Mirror and Witness that I'm trying to set up for high-availability. I've created certificates specifying port 7024 because the customer is running in a Workgroup and not a Domain.  I keep getting the attached error when trying to start mirroring.  I've tried specifying 7024 as the TCP port in the SQL Configuration Manager. Is there something I'm missing?  Does the port for the Mirroring endpoint need to be different from the Principal?  I've tried searching here for the same error but I'm getting mixed information about this.

[image]

The error message shown is:

> The server network address "TCP://kb-versiosql1:7024" can not be reached or does not exist. Check the network address name and that the ports for the local and remote endpoints are operational. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1418)

Comment: does kb-versiosql1 resolve?

Comment: Yes but only because there's an entry in the Windows hosts file.  All machines are visible across the network using either IPs or hostnames.

Comment: use Test-NetConnection https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/test-netconnection?view=win10-ps

Comment: The port numbers can be the same if they are unused by any other application and these are different servers. Can you run a telnet on each participating server of the database mirroring to make sure you can talk to each server via that port.  Also since you are using SQL 2017 hopefully enterprise, did you know SQL v.NEXT has the AG feature which does not require an underlying cluster? Database mirroring has been deprecated and soon no longer supported by Microsoft.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of AG but unfortunately this cluster is running SQL Standard. I'll give telnet a try.

Comment: Great! I noticed on your mirror server that the mirror database is not in restoring state. For mirroring to work, the mirrored database has to be in the NO RECOVERY state.

Comment: @samosql Telnet shows that the ports are open and communicating.

Comment: The strange thing now is that I'm getting an error saying "The database can't be opened. It's in the middle of a restore." I can upload another screenshot but i'm not sure if that's allowed since it's kind of a different issue...

Comment: We ran into this several years ago (2012), and, if I remember correctly, since you are not in a Domain, you have to create the certificates, then the endpoints, and associate them to the certificates, which can only be done via t-sql and not the gui.

Comment: Thanks @rvsc48. Yes, that's what I've done. The certificates are where the port was specified. I just don't think I've done it correctly. I'm going to re-trace my steps and see what I've missed.

Comment: Sounds good.  I was able to locate the scripts I used to make it work.  If you would like to see them, just let me know.  Good Luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who commented!  Your suggestions were all extremely helpful.  I was able to re-trace my steps and did the following:

- Made sure certificates were created for both partners, AND Witness authorized using the correct logins and '.cer' files.

  - Allowed CONNECT permission on login for remote mirroring endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly an answer to your question, but it might be something of interest to you. There are Basic Availability Groups in SQL Server 2016 and 2017 Standard Edition - a limited AG feature that may be suitable for some mirroring situations (see limitations).

[Basic Availability Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/basic-availability-groups-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Thanks, Blażej. Unfortunately we have 3 databases that need to be mirrored, which exceeds the limitation of Basic AG.